# What situations do single core threading beat threads across cores

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, multicore

Im trying to find real world examples where there might be more advantages to running threads on a single core vs spanning multiple cores.

Is there a cost to spawning threads across cores vs spawning in the same core.

How does java (or the os) determine when to allocate work on specific cores.

Finally, is there a way to specify explicitly that threads should run on a specific core or is this os level determined?

Comment: Did you mean “multiple processors” instead of “multiple processes” in that first sentence? That changes the meaning of your question, so be precise.

Comment: Yes update to core to explicitly mean CPU core. Not spawning OS level processes but having the same say java process spawn threads that run on different cpu cores

Comment: You’ll need to define the criteria by which to judge “beat” as used in title.

Comment: Fair point, I'm mostly trying to understand if there is cost to multiple core execution. I can see issue as mentioned in the below answer of context switching CPU bound tasks. But for none CPU bound tasks where threads are mostly waiting for something is there a cost/benefit to doing this across cores or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the logic is CPU bound, you only want a single thread per core because multiple CPU bound threads on the same core lead to waste due to context switching, cold caches etc. If the thread isn't CPU bound, but I/O bound, it could be beneficial to use multiple threads per core. But this depends on the architecture, e.g. in thread per core architectures like Seastar/Scylla, you still want a single thread per core.

Java doesn't do anything to determine how threads get mapped to cores. That is a task of the OS since Java threads are tied to a native thread.

In Java, there is no out-of-the-box solution to pin threads to cores. But you can use taskset for that or use one of Peter Lawrey's libraries:

https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity

Comment: Thanks, I assumed this to be the case. But what I don't understand is won't context switching happen anyway as the os will have is own work to do so even limiting threads to number of cores for CPU bound tasks the os will still interupt to do it's things

Comment: More over for non CPU bound tasks like spawning web requests and waiting for responses. Would this still benefit multi core, or is there a cost to this that single core muti threads doesn't have?

Comment: I can only say something about Linux. It depends. A lot of work from the OS is handled through interrupts, e.g. when packets are received from the network. And if there are sufficient cores and there is only 1 thread per core, then there will be very few context switches.

Comment: In case of spawning requests and waiting for responses: eventually, a single CPU will become a bottleneck and you need to scale up to multiple cores. Multiple cores can help to reduce latency since there is less queueing of requests/responses.

Comment: Yeah understood that eventually a single core would be bottleneck with multiple requests. I'm mostly just asking an academic question that given say just two requests or anything that's not cpu bound where threads are essentially waiting is there ANY cost to this happening in two cores vs one?

Comment: I'm sure there are certain costs in both directions. Threads sharing a core can cause contention on the CPU, thrash each other caches etc. But threads on different CPUs on different NUMA nodes for example could also run into a performance penalty if they need to access shared memory. In this case you get costs due to cache invalidations, and extra latency to cross the NUMA interconnect. It is very difficult to give a one fits all answer to such a question.

Answer (score 0):

> How does java (or the os) determine when to allocate work on specific cores.

Currently in Java implementations based on OpenJDK, Java threads are mapped one-to-one with host OS threads. So the host OS on each platform (macOS, Linux, BSD, Windows, AIX, etc.) schedules each Java thread for execution on which core as it sees fit.

We as Java programmers have no direct control over when our Java thread is scheduled for execution time. Nor do we control which core performs the execution.

> is there a way to specify explicitly that threads should run on a specific core

No, not in Java.

> Is there a cost to spawning threads across cores vs spawning in the same core.

We cannot restrict our Java threads to specific cores. So the second part of your question makes no sense.

As for a cost to spawning threads, yes there is a significant cost in current Java. Threads currently use quite a bit of memory (stack allocations) and CPU time (CPU core can sit idle while Java code blocks).

Project Loom is an effort to greatly reduce this cost. The main thrust of their efforts is [virtual threads](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8277131), also known as fibers.
Experimental builds of Project Loom technology are available now, based on early-access Java 18. To learn more, see videos of recent presentations and interviews done by members of the Loom team such as Ron Pressler and Alan Bateman.

To learn much more on threading in Java, read this excellent book by Brian Goetz et al.: [Java Concurrency In Practice](https://jcip.net/).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't asking if there is a cost to spawning threads, that's there no matter where it's scheduled to execute. I'm asking if there is a cost to two threads been executed on different cores. Understood that I'm java it's pretty much out of control but from a purely academic point of view is there a cost to this?

Comment: I'm not that sure that Java threads consume a lot of memory due to their stack. On Linux, you can allocate memory for a certain address range, but it will be initialized with a shared zero page. So if the thread stacksize is 512*4096=2MB; it might be that only the first few pages actually need to be allocated, because they are written to, and the rest are just the zero page.  I haven't done any benchmarks, so I could be wrong. But I would be surprised if Java threads eagerly allocate their stacks.

Comment: @pveebtjer Virtual memory may alleviate some of that burden, but better to avoid. Because the host OS does not know the context of the Java code, the host OSes generically allocate a relatively large stack. Even with virtual memory, millions of threads * 2 MB may be problematic. More significantly, once used the stack memory is typically not surrendered – the stack does not shrink. Project Loom addresses both those aspects with virtual threads: (a) allocating a smaller stack initially, and (b) shrinking the stack when no longer needed. See talks by Ron Pressler, of the Project Loom team.

Answer (score 0):

> What situations do single core threading beat threads across cores

Extremely few if any.  The short answer is that you should trust the JVM and the operating system to do the right thing in terms of thread scheduling.

> Is there a cost to spawning threads across cores vs spawning in the same core.

There is a cost in that when a job is swapped out of a processor and another one takes its place, its cached memory [should be] invalidated.  Switching back and forth between processors can affect the memory cache rates and the performance of the memory operations causing initial memory accesses to take longer.

> How does java (or the os) determine when to allocate work on specific cores.

It doesn't.  It is up the native thread libraries on the operating system.

> Finally, is there a way to specify explicitly that threads should run on a specific core or is this os level determined?

There are some native calls that control locking jobs to particular cores.
I'm not sure if there to limit the native thread libraries.  That said I really doubt it would be worthwhile.  It is 2021 and modern operating systems are super efficient at swapping jobs between cores and managing it effectively.  You could make a whole bunch of native calls that would only work on your specific operating system (maybe specific operating system version) and you could easily make your system perform worse and take up more resources.